# Run mysqld_safe in background

Tags: bash, software-installation, mysql

I have a bash script that installs mysql for me.

One line, that executes `mysqld_safe`, makes the script to hang - it won't continue to the following code.

Obviously there's ampersand at line's end, but it won't help, see:

```
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install# /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --ledir=/usr/local/mysql/libexec &
[1] 20131
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install# 130531 17:45:54 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/var/dor-desktop.err'.
130531 17:45:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var
^C
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install#
```

You can see that only `CTRL+C` helps to exit, but it exits my entire bash script...

I've also tried using `nohup`, still didn't help, see:

```
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install# nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --ledir=/usr/local/mysql/libexec &
[1] 19751
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
^C
[1]+  Exit 1                  nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --ledir=/usr/local/mysql/libexec
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install#
```

Any idea how to force `mysqld_safe` to run in background?

---

**Edit (May 31, 16:37 UTC):**

The error log, `'/usr/local/mysql/var/dor-desktop.err'`:

```
130531 18:03:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var
130531 18:03:55 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
130531 18:03:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130531 18:03:55  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130531 18:03:55  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
130531 18:03:55  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130531 18:03:56  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130531 18:03:56  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
130531 18:03:56  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 0
130531 18:03:56 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.57-log'  socket: '/usr/local/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
130531 18:08:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/var/dor-desktop.pid ended
130531 18:17:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var
130531 18:17:09 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
130531 18:17:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130531 18:17:09  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130531 18:17:09  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130531 18:17:09  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
130531 18:17:09  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
130531 18:17:09 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
130531 18:17:09 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
130531 18:17:09 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
130531 18:17:09 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.57-log'  socket: '/usr/local/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
130531 18:21:14 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var
130531 18:21:14 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
130531 18:21:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130531 18:21:14  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130531 18:21:14  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130531 18:21:14  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
130531 18:21:14  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
130531 18:21:14 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
130531 18:21:14 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
130531 18:21:14 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
130531 18:21:14 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.57-log'  socket: '/usr/local/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

---

**Edit #2 (May 31, 16:46 UTC):**

**Sorry!** I forgot to add that immediately after executing mysqld_safe, there's a `wait`  command.
The `wait` command exists in order to make sure that the daemon has started, so that I'd be able to execute `mysql -u root`.
Please wait, perhaps I'll find a solution.

Comment: It is running in the background, but looks like its dieing. What does the error log say?

Comment: @jordanm: I've added the error log in my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I got to a solution:

```
# Wait for the mysqld_safe process to start
while ! [[ "$mysqld_process_pid" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; do
  mysqld_process_pid=$(echo "$(ps -C mysqld -o pid=)" | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g')
  sleep 1
done
```

Explanation:
The wait command that was executed immediately after executing `mysqld_safe`, was waiting for `mysqld_safe` (which is obvious), but I needed it to wait for `mysqld` which is initiated by the user `mysql`! The process `mysqld_safe` would never change it's state (it's in a never-ending loop), therefore the `wait` command waits forever!

So I wrote a code that waits for `mysqld` process to start.

Comment: Why don't you use the stop/start script to bring the DB up and down correctly. Killing it this way is a hack.

Comment: @sim: you mean `service mysql stop` ? You're right... I should have used that. Thanks for noting!

Comment: For the curious, nowadays in systemd times it’s sometimes easier to just start mysqld manually, if running inside a chrooted system. So this actually was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you database has gotten corrupted. I'd take a look at his post over on dba.stackexchange.com for steps on what to do next. This looks to be a database issue and nothing to do with your script.

- [MySQL Innodb corruption](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/mysql-innodb-corruption)

Comment: I'm killing the mysqld process so the result is probably a corrupted InnoDB database. Anyway my script can remove & install the database with a single click so it's not a problem :)